# What does the phrase "waiting for the proper gear" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

Could anyone please tell me the meaning of the phrase "waiting for the proper gear" in the following sentence:

> Hidden beneath her casual demeanor lies a formidable fighter, **waiting for the proper gear** to unleash her complete combat expertise.

I am not sure if the word "gear" means here "equipment" or "conditions". I hope native speakers can confirm its meaning.

For some context, the character is an IT expert in a space adventure game.

Comment: I agree that it probably means "equipment".  I cannot think of any context in which *gear* means "conditions"; did you look it up in a dictionary?  I also find this sentence somewhat unnatural; I wonder if the writer was not a native English speaker.  (Or the writer was trying to write in what they thought was a "fancy" style, and was not very good at it.)